# capturing touches, storing in an array and then animating the array contents

Tags: objective-c, arrays, animation

I am new to Objective-C but I have made some progress with my app through the vast amount of information online. My objective is to press a record button, then move an icon representing a ball across a view. I will capture the touches in an array then replay the movement of the ball by animating the touches by stepping through the coordinates in the array on clicking a play button.

The code I am testing is attempting to step through the array and animate each set of co-ordinates in turn. Only the last animation happens. I guess my whole approach might be incorrect. Please offer me some help and thanks for your time.

```
NSMutableArray *yourCGPointsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[yourCGPointsArray addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(300, 001)]];
[yourCGPointsArray addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(300, 300)]];
[yourCGPointsArray addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(001, 300)]];
int i;
i=0;
while (i < 3) {
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
    [UIView setAnimationDelay:1.0];
    CGPoint point = [[yourCGPointsArray objectAtIndex:i] CGPointValue];
    player3.center = CGPointMake(point.x , point.y);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
    NSLog (@"i array %d", i);
    NSLog (@"cgpoint x %f", point.x);
    NSLog (@"cgpoint y %f", point.y);
    i = i + 1;

}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your approach is incorrect. Right now, your code fires off three animations at essentially the same time -- the while loop won't wait for one animation to complete before starting the next. Instead, you should start one animation, wait for it to complete, start the next, wait for it to complete, and so on. You can do this by using a completion block with each animation to start the next animation. Take a look at `+animateWithDuration:animations:completion:`, for example. It allows you to specify the completion block for the animation.